# Does a good list of open-content RPGs exist?

Tags: game-recommendation

I'm looking for open RPGs to play with my group. By "open-content" I mean games that are licensed similar to open-source software—everyone is allowed to get and modify the game and release the result.

The background is that I don't want to rely too much on a system that might die if its creator drops it for whatever reason. If a game is open-content, I and any community that is interested in it can work on it to keep it alive, at least as long as the campaign runs.

So I would appreciate any listing of such games to pick some from for playing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Year of Living Free](http://livingfree.wikidot.com/) wiki is stuffed with great games using various licenses.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [list of open-content games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Gaming#Open_games) at Wikipedia. It's not a complete list, but there are enough systems there to keep one group busy for several years.

Answer (score 2):

John Kim’s various lists are fairly comprehensive. He has [one for open gaming](http://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/copyright/opengaming.html).

Answer (score 1):

RPG.net has a Wiki entry for open content games [here](http://wiki.rpg.net/index.php/Open_Game_Systems)

imPresa Express is missing from that list, link [here](http://www.pigames.net/collaborative/index.php?action=list&site=2)